# codeignighter redirect issues to refresh

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

I have a registration page.after completing the registration the user will redirect to a new page. In new page when I click the back button I redirect to last page with last data filled up.how to refresh the page to delete form data. The framework is codeignighter.

Comment: Before we can help you we need to see some code with an explanation of what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh or redirect page in codeigniter there is function `redirect(YOUR_URL)`.

Have a Look in [Helper class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to browser back button keep autocomplete off for the form fields in your first form 
You can use autocomplete for the complete form

```
<form action="/action_page.php" autocomplete="off">
```

Or specifically to each control as

```
<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
```

You can also make it on for specific controls/entire form if you need it

if your problem still persists you could use

```
<body onload="document.refresh();">
```

This shall refresh the page on loading for the first time

include this in your page if required to force reset the form on load if you need you can bind this with a javascript onload function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
</script>
```

in case of application back button {if used with href or redirect()}

Shall keep form clean even if autocomplete is not set unless the user takes from browser autofill or you fill them with code